# create a snapshot for EBS without a reboot using python boto module

Tags: python, boto, boto3

Is it possible to create snapshot for EBS without a reboot. I'm planing to write a script to take snapshots on regular basics for running instances(Using python boto module). I go through the boto documentation, but didn't find any. Can someone please help on this.

Comment: what did the boto3API  script show you?

Comment: create a snapshot using  volume_id.

create_snapshot(volume_id, "Description")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already read this :

> "To create a snapshot for EBS volumes that serve as root devices, you
>   should stop the instance before taking the snapshot."

This is typical sysops operation. Unless you are 100% sure that no cache data  pending writing to EBS block, then you can create EBS snapshot without stopping instances.

HOWEVER,

1. if such EBS is used to launch your instances (as mentioned above), part of the OS swap spaces might sit inside EBS, this is still not very serious, since you can recreate swap.  But you will NEVER want to deal with partially written OS update (that might run in the background )
2. If your EBS is used as Database store, then you should stop ALL services that tap into the EBS.  In fact, stopping the instances is 100% guarantee that no forgotten services(that you launch and not sure what they are doing)  writing to EBS.

A corrupted EBS snapshot is not something snapshot make for.